# Is the height of a tree with respect to nodes or path?

Tags: binary-tree

In samsung technical test Question was asked whether this statement is true or not:

> Maximum number of nodes in a binary tree is **2^(h+1)-1** where **h** is the height of tree.

I think it's false because according to Schaum's Series TMH height is defined as the maximum number of nodes till the leaf is reached.

Is it correct or not?

Comment: Please don't shout in the title (no caps lock please).

Comment: @gray, it would be great if you review your edit and edit once, instead of many times in three seconds. That way, if somebody else wants to edit over your edit, they keep getting notification that there already was an edit. They go out, only to see almost nothing has changed, losing their changes so far.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I will be more careful in the future. Thank you for the feedback @Shahbaz, I had no idea it affected anyone else.

Comment: @gray, It's sometimes annoying. It's more annoying when you see someone answer a question, then every 2 seconds update it. You have to keep clicking to refresh and lose track of what was changed. Usually though they do it to become [the fastest gun in stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/169090), mostly to hoard reputation. Quite a dirty trick.

Comment: If you have two conflicting definitions of height, then well, there's a problem right here, you need to choose which one you will use. Most sources define height as the maximal number of *edges* in a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two conventions to define the height of binary 
 1) Maximum Number of nodes from root to leaf 
 2) Maximum Number of edges from root to leaf

Please refer following article

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-method-to-find-height-of-binary-tree/

Comment: Yes that's what confused me. I have already gone through the article.Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is correct. A zero-height binary tree has at most one node, a tree of height one has at most 3 nodes and so on.

Answer (score 1):

True, Maximum number is reached when each node has two children - so we have power of 2. Just draw the tree with all leafs at each level and you will see the formula.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Properties_of_binary_trees) that statement is true

Comment: but according to TMH height=level+1

Comment: @user2828121 if you're not going to consider our answers then why bother asking in the first place ? three people +wikipedia are telling that statement is correct , you choose

Comment: why r u getting annoyed? I was just confirming TMH is the standard book.Noone has asked you to answer....

Comment: `according to TMH` — *My* Schaum's defines it like everyone else and differently from yours. You've just got a bad textbook, that's all. Don't worry, it doesn't matter, most of them suck anyway.